# Is there a MonoTouch wrapper for UIImage-DSP library?

Tags: ios, uiimage, xamarin.ios, blur

I'm searching for a MonoTouch wrapper (or a complete port) of this library:

https://github.com/gdawg/uiimage-dsp

UIImage Image Processing extensions using the vDSP/Accelerate framework.

Fast Image Blur/Sharpen/Emboss/Matrix operations for UIImage.

REQUIRES IOS 4.0 and The Accelerate framework.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Never seen it before (and looks interesting) but here's a small tip: You should reuse your existing account and vote/accept answers to your previous questions. More people are likely to want to respond if you have more "points" yourself.

Comment: How I can reuse my existing account? I just logged with Facebook after some time and it created a new account different from my previous one, but I didn't changed anything. How can I join my two accounts? I cannot even access to the original one anymore. :(

Answer (score 0):

You won't find bindings for it - at least not in it's actual form. Quote from the URL you supplied:

> Copy the UIImage+DSP.h and UIImage+DSP.m classes into your project

So it's not **yet** a library. Someone could maybe it one from the code but, until then, you won't find bindings for it.

As for a complete port the next quote

> these aren't quite as fast

makes it sounds like translating the code to C# (lots of array, bounds checks... even if they could be eliminated with **unsafe** code) is not the best option. I suggest you keep looking at another (OpenGL-ES maybe?) solution - like your previous question here: [How to do a motion blur effect on an UIImageView in Monotouch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475610/how-to-do-a-motion-blur-effect-on-an-uiimageview-in-monotouch)

Maybe even add a bounty once you get enough reputation points :-)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a native port of the blur and tint UIImage categories from WWDC for Monotouch.

- https://github.com/lipka/MonoTouch.UIImageEffects

It uses the Accelerate.framework - you can possible extend on it if it doesn't exactly suit your needs.