# Blur image with GPUImage framework

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Would someone like to shed some light on how GPUImage framework for blur images works under the hood?

Comment: @Brad Larson can help you out in it.

Comment: See also [my answer to "Motion Blur effect on UIImage on iOS"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681962/motion-blur-effect-on-uiimage-on-ios/14840266#14840266) where I describe the newer zoom and motion blurs, in addition to the Gaussian ones mentioned in the linked question. Future questions about the internal workings of the framework might be more appropriate on the GitHub repository, because they are fairly localized.